# What's the word to describe a person like that?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word to describe a person who has a big ambition, likes to become one of richest men in the world. but he won't take certain action to achieve it, likes wouldn't even bother to get started with doing small business. He thinks and talks a lot but done little.

What do you describe that kind of person in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He who thinks and talks a lot about his big plans for the future, without doing anything concrete in the way of materializing them, is usually called a [**dreamer**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dreamer):

> **2** A person who is unpractical or idealistic.

Comment: thanks. are there any idiomatic adjectives to describe this  kind of behavior?

Comment: @user239460 _Unpractical_. _Idealistic_.